# React-hook-form with Material-ui textfield without autoFocus defaultValue disappeared during form submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield, react-hook-form

I have problem using react-hook-form v7 + material-ui textfield. The defaultValue working if I set autoFocus or I manually change the textfield value. However if I just submit without mouse click on the filed that not autoFocus, the defaultValue disappeared during the form submit. Please check [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-formmaterial-ui-problem-gj29w)

- Test 1: don't touch anything, click submit, you will see submit value only has title but missing name and desc [image: result]
- Test 2: mouse click or change value in name, you will see after submit the value of name is there
  [image]

My question is how to make this default value always submit even though without mouse click or change the value of the textField?

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for @micFung solution. The major problem of this one is material-ui and react-hook-form are using different keys inputRef vs ref. There are 2 solutions 1. use react form controller https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-formmaterial-ui-problem-forked-tf14z?file=/src/App.tsx 2. manually map inputRef and ref https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-formmaterial-ui-problem-forked-yrmmr?file=/src/App.tsx:1188-1196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use Material-ui with react-hook-form. It is better to wrap it with `Controller` to allow react-hook-form to link with the 3rd party library element.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

**Wrap Textfield with Controller**

```js
const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
...

<Controller
    render={({ field }) => (
    <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="title"
        label="Title"
        type="text"
        fullWidth
        {...field}
    />
    )}
    control={control}
    name="title"
    defaultValue={data.title}
/>
...
```

After that, the default value will be able to work as expected.

Here is the [codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-formmaterial-ui-problem-forked-tf14z?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Thanks @micFung , this is working solution. An extra, I would like to know if there is solution without using Controller ? just use register?

Comment: Yes you can. but you need to set the ref yourself explicitly because the input ref in material-ui is called `inputRef` instead of `ref` so the `register()` provided `ref` cannot be mapped correctly.

Comment: Here is the codesandbox for demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-formmaterial-ui-problem-forked-yrmmr?file=/src/App.tsx:1188-1196

Comment: Awesome, I see the problem now. Thanks so much. I wish material-ui or react-hook-form could make it computable one day :-) . Great answer and explanation @micFung